# MYSQL select only part of a column

Tags: php, mysql, json

I running a simple mysql query and trying to grab from the src column but I only want to grab the "video#.mp4" part - not the whole value (see picture attached below)

If anyone knows how to achieve this... I really appreciated it! Thank you for any help!

[image]

**Code:**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","test","123","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="SELECT id, title, src, type, poster_img FROM TABLE_NAME";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{

$id = 0;
// Fetch one and one row
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{

// Show video#.mp4 here ///
echo '';

$id++;   

}

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: What MySQL version do you use?

Comment: by using php or MYSQL? i suggest you to store quality and name in 2 columns

Comment: And depending on what version, what data type is the `src` column?

Comment: You appear to have entered JSON into that field; not really a good idea.

Comment: one suggestion is that, use json_decode and get the mp4 index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to store `quality` and `video name` in 2 different columns, because this will help you in searching etc.

In your example, you can achieve your desired result by using `json_decode` but again, it will work if you have valid `json` in `src` column.

**Example:**

```
$string = '[{"quality":"default","mp4":"video2.mp4"}]';
$array = json_decode($string,true);
print_r($array);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [quality] => default [mp4] => video2.mp4 ) )
```

Now you can get the index `mp4` easily, if you have multiple file format, than you can group than inside your loop.